# read json like facebook json php

Tags: php, json, facebook

i try to read json by php

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "3043252fsdgdf36360354", 
      "name": "name1", 
      "access_token": "CAAIf3VEtVSoBAHrVxHL16zt4H5OvwBmdfgs4F3auPE0NZBx5PmIujBAdqw0Cv4bZACXytT1O1y6FHEZA25E1aqQZD"
    }, 
    {
      "id": "3326848fdgsdfgsdf03424168", 
      "name": "name2", 
      "access_token": "CAAIf3VEtVSoBAJinePVdfgsdfgMxuY3zaj9AimaoKx7VIO9jCqZCHC6ZBixL1n6ZC72LTMn0ZB4T8rOHD27WmzbBVgvUwgspeEZD"
    }}
```

i try by this code

```
$sfgsdfg=  $json_a=json_decode($read,true);


echo  $json_a['data'][3043252fsdgdf36360354];
echo  $json_a['3043252fsdgdf36360354'][access_token];
```

not working with this php code  i need help to read it

i need select access_token by 3043252fsdgdf36360354   as  echo $json_a['data'][3043252fsdgdf36360354]['access_token'];

i need only read by id as . mysql command . select access_token where id ='3326848fdgsdfgsdf03424168';

Comment: i need select access_token by 3043252fsdgdf36360354   as  echo $json_a['data'][3043252fsdgdf36360354]['access_token'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your JSON is missing a `]` character and will cause `json_decode` to return NULL. You should first correct the JSON string. You can use a online service such as [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com) to validate the JSON. Once you've decoded the JSON string as an associative array, you can just loop through the array and check if it contains the given ID in it. If it does, you can grab the corresponding access token easily.

I've made this into a short little function. You can use that to get the access token by ID:

```
$jsonArray = json_decode($str, TRUE);
function getAccessTokenFromID($id, $jsonArray) {
    foreach ($jsonArray['data'] as $k => $elem) {
        if($elem['id'] == $id) {
            $access_token = $elem['access_token'];
        }
    }
    return $access_token;
}
```

Usage:

```
$myid = '3043252fsdgdf36360354';
$my_accesstoken = getAccessTokenFromID($myid, $jsonArray);
```

[**Demo!**](http://codepad.org/xbiszCXI)

Comment: echo getAccessTokenFromID(3043252fsdgdf36360354); not work ??

Answer (score 0):

Isn't well formed json.
Try with:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "3043252fsdgdf36360354", 
      "name": "name1", 
      "access_token": "CAAIf3VEtVSoBAHrVxHL16zt4H5OvwBmdfgs4F3auPE0NZBx5PmIujBAdqw0Cv4bZACXytT1O1y6FHEZA25E1aqQZD"
    }, 
    {
      "id": "3326848fdgsdfgsdf03424168", 
      "name": "name2", 
      "access_token": "CAAIf3VEtVSoBAJinePVdfgsdfgMxuY3zaj9AimaoKx7VIO9jCqZCHC6ZBixL1n6ZC72LTMn0ZB4T8rOHD27WmzbBVgvUwgspeEZD"
    }
  ]
}
```

And php:

```
$val = json_decode($read, TRUE);
echo $val['data'][0]['id'];
```

UPDATED:

```
function find_by_id($id, $val) {
  foreach($val['data'] as $key => $obj) {
    if ($obj['id'] === $id)
      return $obj['access_token'];
  }
}
```

Comment: i need to select access_token by 3326848fdgsdfgsdf03424168  as  echo $val['data'][0]['3326848fdgsdfgsdf03424168'];

Comment: i will save ids and need to select user acsess token of pages and save it for every page

Comment: Do you want a function who return the array who has as id the id who you have specified?

Comment: no i need only read by id as  . mysql command . select access_token where id ='3326848fdgsdfgsdf03424168';